# PhoneGap/WP7 How to save httpRequest result?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I am fairly new to coding and especially phonegap. I am writing an application with phonegap (for windows phone) and I must save some info from server. How can I do that?

```
function handleResponse() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {

        var request_text = request.responseText;
        document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = request_text;

        var object_parse = JSON.parse(request_text);
        var newIp = object_parse.ip;

        if (newIp != 0) {
            myindex++;
           // 
           // save ip
          //  
            //
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends.

If you want to save it for this particular session of your app then just use a `Global Variable`, `array` if more than one ip, to store.
Then you can access these in your app for this session.

If you want to access these for next session too then use `Isolated Storage`, you can get more info [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage).